# Intellij cannot recognize UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, maven, utf-8, intellij-idea

I set all configurations to UTF-8, but after the result of RSA encryption cannot be recognized by Intellij.

Here are my settings:

[image]

[image]

and here is actual encrypted text:
[image: result]

```
 getRSA().init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, readPublicKey());
 return new String(getRSA().doFinal(token.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

I also set in pom.xml

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

and also command line param:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

What can be reason?

Comment: RSA ciphertext is not valid UTF8.

Comment: do you mean this `token.getBytes("UTF-8")`, token is not valid utf-8? it is just sha256 result.

Comment: also - I wouldn't use anything other than US-ASCII for source encoding.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu: I wouldn't use anything other than UTF8, _ever_.

Comment: @SLaks others may have trouble reading your code.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu: Other people should not have problems reading UTF8.  And dropping characters is not a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to treat arbitrary binary data as if it were UTF-8-encoded text. It's not. It's just arbitrary binary data. What you're doing is like trying to represent an image or music file as text - it simply *isn't* text...

You should use Base64 to convert it to a string instead (e.g. with [this public domain library](http://iharder.net/base64)). See [Marc Gravell's blog post on IO issues](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html) for more background on why this is required.

Note that this is definitely *not* an Intellij problem - it's a problem with the approach you're taking to data.